# VB .net Using Async and Await with while true loop locks UI

Tags: vb.net, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I have a VB.net winform app that I am writing with a WebSocketClient, I have been searching for days to find some documented answers to this specific question but not found anything that I can use.

My Async/await class that is used to talk to the remote server uses a number of await statements, mainly sendasync and receiveasync. The app is similar in functionality to SignalR chat type applications.

I successfully connect to the URI, receive a welcome message and authenticate, still using Async/Await. The button on the form that starts the WebSocketClient is also converted to an async method with the WebSocketClient "awaited".

Then I drop into a while/true loop which should allow the user to send requests and receive feedback from the remote server.

The problem I have is that the UI locks and when the user tries to send a request from a button click is completely unresponsive.

I have managed to get some modicum of success with background workers but I want to use the Async/Await method as it is widely considered to be a more modern approach.

I cannot work out how I get an Async/await structure to emulate the while loop unless I have my final await implementing a while loop which I am sure goes against the design of Async/await and will also probably lock up as well.

Can anyone help me passed this hurdle please?

thanks all,

jON

```
               While True

                If jsonRequestText <> "" Then

                    jsonResponseText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived.Array, 0, result.Count)
                    bytesToSend = New ArraySegment(Of Byte)(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonRequestText))

                    Await ws.SendAsync(bytesToSend, WebSocketMessageType.Text, True, Threading.CancellationToken.None)
                    bytesReceived = New ArraySegment(Of Byte)(New Byte(1023) {})
                    result = Await ws.ReceiveAsync(bytesReceived, Threading.CancellationToken.None)
                    jsonResponseText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived.Array, 0, result.Count)
                    jsonRequestText = ""

                End If

                If jsonResponseText <> "" Then

                    Await ConsumeResponseAsync(jsonResponseText)
                    jsonResponseText = ""

                End If

            End While
```

I am using websocketclient and once I connect and authenticate I drop into the posted loop. I am struggling to work out how I replicate this loop with an async await approach i.e. without while/true.

Comment: You need to post your code. It's not clear how a *while/true loop* could *allow the user to send requests and receive feedback*. Since you're using WinForms, you're in an event-driven platform, `while(true)` loops are not usually welcome, much less when run in the main Thread.

Comment: `I cannot work out how I get an Async/await structure to emulate the while loop` - you await on a [`TaskCompletionSource.Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1.task?view=netcore-3.1), and when your event happens that should break the loop, you [signal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1.setresult?view=netcore-3.1) the `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I started to put some code together to demonstrate but there is a lot of it and really I needed to write a cut down version which I started -  I completely agree Jimi, I really didn't want to use a while(true) - and then I read GSerg's reply and it steered me exactly where I needed to be going I think. thanks again both.